# Memory leak from PopupLayout? Any idea?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I suspect it has to do with SelectionContainer, but I am not sure and can't figure out a solution.

```
D/LeakCanary: Found 2 paths to retained objects
D/LeakCanary: Analysis in progress, 50% done, working on Inspecting objects
D/LeakCanary: Analysis in progress, 60% done, working on Computing native retained size
D/LeakCanary: Analysis in progress, 70% done, working on Computing retained size
I/iq.mliq.: Background concurrent copying GC freed 1217073(30MB) AllocSpace objects, 1(516KB) LOS objects, 29% free, 58MB/82MB, paused 50us total 129.711ms
D/LeakCanary: Analysis in progress, 80% done, working on Building leak traces
D/LeakCanary: Analysis in progress, 90% done, working on Reporting heap analysis
V/SQLiteDatabase: triggerBuildingIndex(): invalid id, return.
D/LeakCanary: ​
D/LeakCanary: ====================================
D/LeakCanary: HEAP ANALYSIS RESULT
D/LeakCanary: ====================================
D/LeakCanary: 1 APPLICATION LEAKS
D/LeakCanary: 
D/LeakCanary: References underlined with "~~~" are likely causes.
D/LeakCanary: Learn more at https://squ.re/leaks.
D/LeakCanary: 
D/LeakCanary: 60230 bytes retained by leaking objects
D/LeakCanary: Displaying only 1 leak trace out of 2 with the same signature
D/LeakCanary: Signature: 6b9af3bfc8523409a555c9e53bc41c4a631fd096
D/LeakCanary: ┬───
D/LeakCanary: │ GC Root: Thread object
D/LeakCanary: │
D/LeakCanary: ├─ android.os.HandlerThread instance
D/LeakCanary: │    Leaking: NO (PathClassLoader↓ is not leaking)
D/LeakCanary: │    Thread name: 'plumber-android-leaks'
D/LeakCanary: │    ↓ Thread.contextClassLoader
D/LeakCanary: ├─ dalvik.system.PathClassLoader instance
D/LeakCanary: │    Leaking: NO (SnapshotKt↓ is not leaking and A ClassLoader is never leaking)
D/LeakCanary: │    ↓ ClassLoader.runtimeInternalObjects
D/LeakCanary: ├─ java.lang.Object[] array
D/LeakCanary: │    Leaking: NO (SnapshotKt↓ is not leaking)
D/LeakCanary: │    ↓ Object[1891]
D/LeakCanary: ├─ androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.SnapshotKt class
D/LeakCanary: │    Leaking: NO (Recomposer↓ is not leaking and a class is never leaking)
D/LeakCanary: │    ↓ static SnapshotKt.applyObservers
D/LeakCanary: ├─ java.util.ArrayList instance
D/LeakCanary: │    Leaking: NO (Recomposer↓ is not leaking)
D/LeakCanary: │    ↓ ArrayList[6]
D/LeakCanary: ├─ androidx.compose.runtime.Recomposer$recompositionRunner$2$unregisterApplyObserver$1 instance
D/LeakCanary: │    Leaking: NO (Recomposer↓ is not leaking)
D/LeakCanary: │    Anonymous subclass of kotlin.jvm.internal.Lambda
D/LeakCanary: │    ↓ Recomposer$recompositionRunner$2$unregisterApplyObserver$1.this$0
D/LeakCanary: ├─ androidx.compose.runtime.Recomposer instance
D/LeakCanary: │    Leaking: NO (CompositionImpl↓ is not leaking and Recomposer is in state Idle)
D/LeakCanary: │    ↓ Recomposer._knownCompositions
D/LeakCanary: ├─ java.util.ArrayList instance
D/LeakCanary: │    Leaking: NO (CompositionImpl↓ is not leaking)
D/LeakCanary: │    ↓ ArrayList[7]
D/LeakCanary: ├─ androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionImpl instance
D/LeakCanary: │    Leaking: NO (Composition not disposed)
D/LeakCanary: │    ↓ CompositionImpl.composer
D/LeakCanary: │                      ~~~~~~~~
D/LeakCanary: ├─ androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl instance
D/LeakCanary: │    Leaking: UNKNOWN
D/LeakCanary: │    Retaining 73.8 kB in 1511 objects
D/LeakCanary: │    ↓ ComposerImpl.insertTable
D/LeakCanary: │                   ~~~~~~~~~~~
D/LeakCanary: ├─ androidx.compose.runtime.SlotTable instance
D/LeakCanary: │    Leaking: UNKNOWN
D/LeakCanary: │    Retaining 37 B in 1 objects
D/LeakCanary: │    ↓ SlotTable.slots
D/LeakCanary: │                ~~~~~
D/LeakCanary: ├─ java.lang.Object[] array
D/LeakCanary: │    Leaking: UNKNOWN
D/LeakCanary: │    Retaining 68.3 kB in 1456 objects
D/LeakCanary: │    ↓ Object[106]
D/LeakCanary: │            ~~~~~
D/LeakCanary: ╰→ androidx.compose.ui.window.PopupLayout instance
D/LeakCanary: ​     Leaking: YES (ObjectWatcher was watching this because androidx.compose.ui.window.PopupLayout received
D/LeakCanary: ​     View#onDetachedFromWindow() callback)
D/LeakCanary: ​     Retaining 30.1 kB in 606 objects
D/LeakCanary: ​     key = 85e935b6-558c-42b2-bb1a-ed54d592fba7
D/LeakCanary: ​     watchDurationMillis = 6822
D/LeakCanary: ​     retainedDurationMillis = 1821
D/LeakCanary: ​     View not part of a window view hierarchy
D/LeakCanary: ​     View.mAttachInfo is null (view detached)
D/LeakCanary: ​     View.mID = R.id.null
D/LeakCanary: ​     View.mWindowAttachCount = 1
D/LeakCanary: ​     mContext instance of ac.mdiq.mliq.elements.EditActivity with mDestroyed = false
D/LeakCanary: ====================================
D/LeakCanary: 0 LIBRARY LEAKS
D/LeakCanary: 
D/LeakCanary: A Library Leak is a leak caused by a known bug in 3rd party code that you do not have control over.
D/LeakCanary: See https://square.github.io/leakcanary/fundamentals-how-leakcanary-works/#4-categorizing-leaks
D/LeakCanary: ====================================
D/LeakCanary: 0 UNREACHABLE OBJECTS
D/LeakCanary: 
D/LeakCanary: An unreachable object is still in memory but LeakCanary could not find a strong reference path
D/LeakCanary: from GC roots.
D/LeakCanary: ====================================
D/LeakCanary: METADATA
D/LeakCanary: 
D/LeakCanary: Please include this in bug reports and Stack Overflow questions.
```